# Alter table in mysql, add column error 1064 (42000)?

Tags: mysql, alter-table

I am trying to add column in mysql table but following error thrown.

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ALTER TABLE `cm_article`  ADD COLUMN `active` INT NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' AFTER `description`'

My Sql Statement is:
ALTER TABLE `cm_article` ADD COLUMN `active` INT NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' AFTER `description`;

Comment: The error can occur if we use single quotes instead of backtick symbol around the column name.

Comment: There are two different types of quotation marks in MySQL. You need to use ` for column names and ' for strings. Since you have used ' for the filename column the query parser got confused.

Comment: The statement works for me. The table name and two column names are enclosed with backticks in your statement, which is correct. What is the MySQL version? Please find out using 'select version();'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two different types of quotation marks in MySQL. You need to use ` for column names and ' for strings. Since you have used ' for the filename column the query parser got confused.

```
ALTER TABLE `cm_article` ADD COLUMN `active` INT NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' AFTER `description` ;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do :

```
ALTER TABLE cm_article
ADD COLUMN active INT NOT NULL DEFAULT(0)
AFTER description;
```

If it doesn't work, modify 'ADD COLUMN' with just 'ADD'

Comment: "If it doesn't work" ?,   And you missed the explanation on why those back-quotes are evil any wayz, and not using back quotes makes life so much easier.